# Did C. S. Lewis indicate how he chose the name "Tash" for the Calormene's demon-god?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, names, the-chronicles-of-narnia

I recently learned that there is an archeological site near Aleppo along the Syrian-Turkish border, called ["Arslan Tash."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arslan_Tash)  The name means "lion stone," apparently in reference to some of the statues and carvings of animals that were known from the site even before it was formally excavated.  It seems unlikely that it is a coincidence that C. S. Lewis, having named his fantasy version of Jesus the lion "Aslan," would have chosen the name of the chief god worshipped by the culturally-Near-Eastern Calormenes to be "Tash" without getting the name from that of the site.  However, I am curious whether he ever commented explicitly on the connection and whether there was more to why he chose the name than just liking the way it sounded and thinking it fit well with the culture of Calormen.  (For comparison, one of the other Calormene deity names in *The Horse and His Boy* is "Azaroth"—which is quite suggestive of the Middle-Eastern goddess, Ishtar/Astarte/Asherah.)

I can see some reasonably hypotheses about how Lewis came to that specific name, but at this point there are purely speculation.  The Louvre in Paris sponsored excavations at the Arslan Tash in 1928 and 1929 (when Syria was under a French-administered League of Nations mandate), and there are a number of nice carvings in the museum's collection.  So Lewis could certainly have seen pieces from Arslan Tash, such as this ivory plaque, on a visit to Paris.

[image: Ivory plaque]

Several of the other pieces in the Louvre are similar, featuring winged humanoids (a very common motif in Assyrian art more generally—although, as in this case, it is often unclear whether the images are meant to depict magical beings or humans in ritual costumes).  [Tash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tash_(Narnia)) is not really described in *The Horse and His Boy*, except as (presumably) an idol in the great temple in the capital city bearing his name, Tashbaan.  In that context, a name meaning "stone" might have seemed particularly apt to Lewis.  On the other hand, when Tash appears in *The Last Battle*, his form, like that carved by the Assyrian artisans, was that of bird-human chimera (although with his bird head and extra limbs, he actually sounds more like [Pazuzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pazuzu) than the winged figures from Arslan-Tash).

So, is any more known about the origin of the name?  Did Lewis detail for any of his correspondents why he picked the name "Tash"?

Comment: More specifically, Azaroth seems evocative of the demon Astaroth, whose name probably comes from the aforementioned deity. C.S. Lewis probably got the name more directly from there.

Comment: @Adamant   Azaroth?   I wonder if Lewis had any familiarity with the Cthulhu Mythos and Azathoth.

Comment: @M.A. Golding - Azathoth could owe something to Astaroth as well, or the alchemical azoth.

Comment: @Adamant  And of course I have to wonder whether those names might have inspired the favorite incantation of Raven in Teen Titans (2003-2006), Teen Titans Go! (2013-), and Titans (2018-2023) "Azarath Metrion Zinthos".